# How to properly remove escaping in node

Tags: node.js

I have the following string which was the result of running a stringify command in node:

```
"{\"packageName\":\"com.something.something\",\"productId\":\"product_credit_50\",\"purchaseTime\":1484696888772,\"purchaseState\":0,\"purchaseToken\":\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.XX-X1Xxx0QZlCo1hk7cEPqocpIpttvxSPCjwf5cqvraOTXAv7k9nglTSCdpWjAuqZ2w1rtRJTYbJ6483YG09huOCQesngxGe_gD_f83mrMsu7Yw5tEioPE1vyORGMVykhykRYn-vaE8TTQ3CgLxFafPJ7cEJwEl59w\"}"
```

The command I used to get the string is as follows:

```
var tmpreceipt = JSON.stringify(googleReceiptData);
```

I then executed the following command to remove the escaped characters:

```
var receipt = tmpreceipt.replace("\\\"", "\"");
```

The problem i have is that it only removes the first "\".  The result of receipt is:

```
"{"packageName\":\"com.something.something\",\"productId\":\"product_credit_50\",\"purchaseTime\":1484696888772,\"purchaseState\":0,\"purchaseToken\":\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.XX-X1Xxx0QZlCo1hk7cEPqocpIpttvxSPCjwf5cqvraOTXAv7k9nglTSCdpWjAuqZ2w1rtRJTYbJ6483YG09huOCQesngxGe_gD_f83mrMsu7Yw5tEioPE1vyORGMVykhykRYn-vaE8TTQ3CgLxFafPJ7cEJwEl59w\"}"
```

What I am doing wrong?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems you should not apply `JSON.stringify` at all, as looks like you already had a JSON string.

Comment: If you're just asking about how to replace all instances of `\"` with `"` instead of just the first, [this explains how to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: i am getting a different problem if I don't use stringify.  do you see any problems with the code I did?  I was expecting that the replace should be able to remove the escaping.

Comment: @Tashi thanks.  That's what I was trying to do.